# Pyspark going extremely slow on Windows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So, I'm trying to build a program that goes through all of the files in a directory, and then uses Spark to read into these files and count the instances of a given word (let's say simply the word "word").
I have a Python function `get_files` that receives a path as an input and returns a string with all of the files in that directory separated by a comma.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
import pyspark
import get_files

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
files = get_files(<path/to/my/files>)
num = sc.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).filter(lambda x: 'word' in x).count()
```

This whole process takes around 40 minutes for a folder with around 120Mb. If  instead I simply build a function with Python (no Spark) that iterates through each of these files, opens them, and counts the words, it just takes a couple of seconds. In case it's important, I'm running Windows with an Intel i5 with 4 cores and 8 logical processors, and with 8Gb RAM.

I've tried several different methods: this was ran on a Jupyter Notebook, but I've tried running it from a Python script, and also from the command prompt. I've also tried configuring the number of cores manually (doing like `local[8]` or `local[7]` instead of `local[*]`) or also tried changing some configuration values regarding the number of workers, or adjusting the number of partitions it creates, but either way it goes super slow.

I also try running `localhost:4040` and I can see that it does generate several partitions and it is using all cores. When going to the "Executors" sections, I can see there's one executor running, using all 8 cores. **strong text**

Comment: i always run my spark applications with `local[1]`, this is one thread. On you local setup you should be fine with `local[1]` or `local[2]`

Comment: can you share of the `get_files()` output?

Comment: Spark is geared toward parallelization. Running code on a local machine is for testing and it will never be faster then python because there is overhead associated with spark session. rewrite `get_files()` in spark, and try to stick to spark whenever you can.  Also, `local[*]` will utilize all the available cores in your machine.

Comment: @SQL.injection I didn't add my get_files output mainly because I made sure that output was correct, and also because it's a super long string with around 20,000 files, and the string looks like this "C:\\...\\...\\file1.py,C:\\...\\\file2.py,C:\\...\\file3.py".